# how to insert the value of textbox in another textbox value in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a id no.
TRN-000001

in other way ill input the batch and get the value of batch and the result is passing into the middle of the idno. like TRN-0001-0000001 the 0001 is the value of batch

Comment: I'm not even sure there is a question here.  Maybe you could update your question with what you've tried so far and what about it isn't meeting the requirements

Comment: `Dim arr = "TRN-000001".Split("-"c)`, then `Dim output = String.Join("-"c, arr.First, "0001", arr.Last)`

Answer (score 1):

I've made a sample program to demonstrate how to solve this problem. In it, we have three text boxes labelled:

- `txtBatchNo`, which is expected to be something like `0001`
- `txtIDNo`, which is expected to be something like `TRN-0000001`
- `txtTransactionCode`, which is where the result will be placed

Here is some code:

```
Public Class Form1
    '
    '  Whenever the txtBatchNo Text changes, it will update the transaction code
    '
    Private Sub txtBatchNo_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBatchNo.TextChanged
        txtTransactionCode.Text = MakeTransactionCode(txtIDNo.Text, txtBatchNo.Text)
    End Sub
    '
    '  Whenever the txtIDNo Text changes, it will update the transaction code
    '
    Private Sub txtIDNo_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtIDNo.TextChanged
        txtTransactionCode.Text = MakeTransactionCode(txtIDNo.Text, txtBatchNo.Text)
    End Sub
    '
    '  This function will take apart the IDNo and insert the Batch No
    '
    Private Function MakeTransactionCode(ByVal IDNo As String, ByVal BatchNo As String) As String
        '
        '  ID No is expected to be something like "TRN-0000001"
        '  BatchNo is expected to be something like "0002"
        '
        '
        '  Split the ID No into parts using the dash.  The parts should be:
        '       strIDNoParts(0) = "TRN"
        '       strIDNoParts(1) = "0000001"
        '
        '  Notice that neither parts have a dash in them
        '
        Dim strIDNoParts As String() = IDNo.Split("-")
        '
        '  Check to make sure you have at least two parts, otherwise the code will crash
        '
        If strIDNoParts.Length > 1 Then
            '
            '  Now reassemble your Transaction code
            '     Remember that the strIDNoParts array is zero-based, not 1-based.
            '     We need to add the dashes back in that were taken out by the split function.
            '
            Dim strTransactionCode As String = strIDNoParts(0) & "-" & BatchNo & "-" & strIDNoParts(1)
            Return strTransactionCode
        Else
            '
            '  If there was only one part or zero parts, return an empty string
            '
            Return ""
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```